# WinSCP authenticate to the server in automation mode, using the public key authentication

Tags: scripting, public-key, winscp

I am using WinSCP to automate the copy process to server and the authentication is only with username and password.

Script is:

```
open username:password@ipaddress:portno -hostkey=<hostkey>
```

Whereas now the authentication mode has to be changed to public key.

Script changed for authenticate through public key:

```
open username@ipaddress:portno -privatekey=mykey.ppk
```

Passphrase for the private key is requested after executing the above script, but is there any way that the passphrase of the private key can be provided in the same command?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`-passphrase` switch of the `open` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open#passphrase).

See also WinSCP FAQ 
[How can I connect without entering private key passphrase each time?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_passphrase)

---

Also, note, that you still should use the `-hostkey` switch.

---

```
open username:password@ipaddress:portno -hostkey=... -privatekey=... -passphrase=...
```