# Transfer Files through FTP in Windows Batch Scripts having Private Key

Tags: windows, batch-file, sftp, private-key

I am using these command to transfer a file to an SFTP location.It has an private key(Puttygen) with
passphrase.

```
open ftp://%1%:%2%@%3%/ -explicittls -certificate="32:4b:5e:a7:05:b9:e4:2d:7d:44:cb:c1:0e:ee:0e:17"-privatekey=D:\SSIS_DEV\DBTeam\Transfer\Rural\Private.ppk 

put %4%
```

I am getting a timeout error while connecting.

```
exit
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use SFTP, but use FTP (`ftp://`) protocol in the [session URL](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/session_url).

Use `sftp://` instead:

```
open sftp://%1%:%2%@%3%/
```

---

FTP and SFTP are two completely different and incompatible protocols. You get the timeout, because you are trying to connect to the FTP port, which the server does not listen on.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It is getting connected now, but getting a authentication failure. The Private key contains a passphrase, could you please let me how can I give the passphrase in the script.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/19953167/850848